# prevent nested lists / bullet points within a HTML Table Cell from overflowing cell

Tags: html, css

I have a HTML table which has 4 columns. The last column displays some HTML formatted data ( output generated from FCKEditor - just like this editor) - e.g. Bold, underline, italic text etc.
The problem occurs when the formatted data in this last cell is a HTML unordered List. (UL, LI etc) - when there is such a list, the bullet points occupy the preceding cell.
Any idea how to confine my lists to the one table cell (TD)?

Answer (score 2):

Try setting  `list-style-position:inside;` on your ul.  By default the markers are placed outside of the content flow.